# How does one measure angles in minutes and seconds?

Tags: geometry

I've searched for an answer on Google, and I really do not understand it at all. Can someone please explain it to me in the simplest terms possible?

Comment: 60 minutes in a degree, 60 seconds in a minute. These units have nothing to do with time.

Comment: Yeah.  Just go with that conversion by Jiang.  1 degree is 60 minutes.  $\frac{1}{2}degree$ is 30 minutes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A degree is like an hour; it is equivalent to 60 minutes. As expected, there are 60 seconds in a minute. The analogy with time seems perfect but it’s not analogous with a clock.

Answer (score 1):

In DMS notation, there are 60 minutes in a degree. And 60 seconds in a minute.

$$1^\circ=60'(\text{minutes})=3600''(\text{seconds})$$

So an angle of $~20^\circ~30'~40''$ is the same as $(20+\frac{30}{60}+\frac{40}{3600})=20.511^\circ$